# pandas reshape only two columns

Tags: python, pandas, reshape

Given this sample dataframe:

```
Provider    Month    Active   Acute   Hospital   Total
Joe         January  0        1       0          1
Mary        February 1        3       5          9
Susie       January  2        2       4          8
Susie       January  3        0       0          3
Mary        February 4        3       3          10
Joe         February 1        0       4          5
```

I am trying to reshape the data but only reshaping the Month and Total columns.  I have tried pivot, pivot table, unstack and melt, but no combo seems to work.  The desired dataframe output is below with the "Active" value ***totaled*** under the month column name which is taken from the Month column and all the other values under their column headers as in the above df:

```
Provider    January  Acute   Hospital   Total   February  Acute  Hospital  Total
Joe         0        1       0          1       1         0      4         5
Susie       5        2       4          11      0         0      0         0
Mary        0        0       0          0       5         6      8         19
```

So, the "Active" values from the above dataframe now appear under the Month Name and the remainder stay where they are.  Ideas?  I am sure it is some combo of various reshaping tools that will get me there, but I haven't been able to make that connection just yet.

Comment: Why don't you `pivot` and get a multindex? That will be less ambiguous than having duplicated column names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to use a `pivot_table` with a MultiIndex:

```
df2 = (    df.pivot_table(index='Provider', columns='Month', fill_value=0, aggfunc='sum', sort=False)
   .swaplevel(axis=1)
   .sort_index(axis=1, level='Month', sort_remaining=False)
 )
```

Output:

```
Month    February                      January                     
           Active Acute Hospital Total  Active Acute Hospital Total
Provider                                                           
Joe             1     0        4     5       0     1        0     1
Mary            5     6        8    19       0     0        0     0
Susie           0     0        0     0       5     2        4    11
```

If you insist on having the provided format, you can rework the column headers (but will have ambiguous duplicated names):

```
df2.columns = df2.columns.map(lambda x: x[0] if x[1]=='Active' else x[1])
```

Output:

```
          February  Acute  Hospital  Total  January  Acute  Hospital  Total
Provider                                                                   
Joe              1      0         4      5        0      1         0      1
Mary             5      6         8     19        0      0         0      0
Susie            0      0         0      0        5      2         4     11
```

Comment: Your solution includes months in alphabetical order. I think, the order should be the natural sequence of months.

Comment: @Valdi_Bo I didn't include it as I'm typing on a phone (pain to do), but this is easily solved with a custom key or an ordered Categorical index.

Comment: Thanks @mozway.  This worked perfectly.  I should have thought about a multi index ahead of time, but still, your answer would be something I would not have come across easily.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that you should have a **MultiIndex** on columns of
the result.
The first level should be month name and the second - names of your source
columns with integer data.
See column names in the final result.

Start from creation of a list of months:

```
months = ['January', 'February']
```

If you have more months in the source DataFrame, extend the above list
so that it includes all existing months.

Then create an auxiliary DataFrame - a *pivot_table* from the source DataFrame:

```
wrk = df.pivot_table(index='Provider', columns='Month', aggfunc='sum',
    fill_value=0)
```

For now it has wrong order of levels in columns, so the next step is to
reverse it:

```
wrk.columns = wrk.columns.swaplevel()
```

And to get the intended result, reindex *wrk*:

```
result = wrk.reindex(columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
    months, ['Active', 'Acute', 'Hospital', 'Total']]), fill_value=0)
```

I added *fill_value* in the last instruction, to have a month filled
with zeroes if your source data failed to include data from this month.
Try e.g. to add *'March'* to *months* and you will see the result.

For your source data, the result is:

```
         January                      February                     
          Active Acute Hospital Total   Active Acute Hospital Total
Provider                                                           
Joe            0     1        0     1        1     0        4     5
Mary           0     0        0     0        5     6        8    19
Susie          5     2        4    11        0     0        0     0
```

Note that the order of rows is ascending and in my opinion the result
should be just like above (your expected result contains rows placed
in an arbitrary order).